# Smoke shows in rendered view but not in final PNG sequence. Smoke has material

Tags: rendering, error

Smoke shows in rendered view but not in final PNG sequence. Smoke has material. I accidently deleted Composite nodes and re-entered them manually. thinking that may have something to do with the problem? I've been through several threads and cannot find a fix that works. what am i missing?? [image]